# Cannot open question that contains only formulas

Tags: bug, mathjax, titles, ipad

On an iPad, when I press and hold on the title of a question that contains only formulas, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321892/lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracn-sqrtnn-e), I get "Copy" instead of the usual "Open / Open in New Tab / ..." menu.

If I just tap on the title, it works as expected, but I wanted to open it in a new tab.

Any way around that?

Comment: There is at least one prior question on this topic iirc.

Comment: I like to right click -> open in new tab when I'm browsing MSE, and this doesn't work on formulas either.  I bet these issues are related.

Comment: related http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/mathjax-menu-obliterates-link-menu-when-the-entire-link-is-latex

Comment: A formula does not constitute a question. So, a solution would be to click on the question, edit the title so that it reads "Why does -formula-?", then go back to where you were and be happy that you and all other iPad users can right click on the question now.